# Magento remove (show/hide editor) button in admin module

Tags: php, magento

i have a custom admin module, in the edit page i have wysiwyg editor, but in the top of it there is a button (show/hide editor), i don't want that button, how can i remove it
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the CMS page WSIWYG editor, and the toggle button has an id of `togglepage_content`, so I was able to hide it with a css rule like this:

```
#togglepage_content { display:none; }
```

Take a look at your button, hopefully it has an ID? If it has the same as another page (the one posted above, for instance), use the class assigned to the body for each action to differentiate further:

```
.adminhtml-cms-page-edit #togglepage_content { display:none; }
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Well, if you're trying to stop users forcibly (e.g. removing the "delete every user" button), CSS is not really an appropriate solution, but this pretty much characterizes low risk.